# Simultaneous rank jumping of elliptic curves over number fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties

Here's something fun that I've been wondering about for a while out of curiosity. It has to do with the rank $\mathrm{rk}(E(K))$ of an elliptic curve $E$ over a number field $K$, and especially how it behaves under finite field extensions.

Let $K$ be a number field and let $p$ be a prime number. Suppose that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are elliptic curves over $K$.

> > Is the set
> > $$\{L/ K \ | \ [L:K] = p, \  rk(E_1(L)) > rk(E_1(K)) \ \textrm{and} \ rk(E_2(L)) > rk(E_2(K)) \}$$
> > infinite?

That is, is the set of degree $p$ extensions $L$ of $K$ such that the rank of $E_1$ in $L$ jumps **and** the rank of $E_2$ jumps in $L$ an infinite set?

If $E_1 = E_2$ (Edit: or $E_1$ and $E_2$ are $K$-isogenous), then the answer is positive. A proof is given in https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.0933

Note that the infinitude of the above set is equivalent to the infinitude of the set
$$\{ L/K \ | \ [L:K] =p, \ E_1(L)\setminus E_1(K) \neq \emptyset  \ \textrm{and} \ E_2(L) \setminus E_2(K) \neq \emptyset\}.$$

Thus, we may also formulate our question as

> > Is the set of degree $p$ extensions $L/K$ such that $E_1$ has a "new" $L$-point and $E_2$ has a "new" $L$-point infinite?

One may ask of course similar questions about abelian varieties. But I do not even know whether the rank of an abelian variety over $\mathbb{Q}$ jumps in infinitely many quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The answer is also positive if the two elliptic curves are isogenous over $K$.

Comment: Yes, good point. The ranks are then equal of course.

Comment: In the linked paper, for $p\geq 5$, the author (Dave Mendes Da Costa) proves the required statement for an elliptic curve $E$ by showing that there is a higher genus curve $C$, a finite morphism $C\to E$ of degree $<p$ and a morphism $C\to \mathbb{P}^1_K$ of degree $p$. The answer to the question would be positive if we could find a higher genus curve $C$ such that there is a finite morphism $C\to E_1$ of degree $<p$, a finite morphism $C\to E_2$ of degree $<p$, and a finite morphism $C\to \mathbb{P}^1_K$ of degree $p$.

Comment: When $p=2$, $K = \mathbb Q$, and $j(E_1)$ and $j(E_2)$ are not simultaneously $0$ or $1728$, then a positive answer follows form Theorem 4 of [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/imrn/article/1993/4/113/674514?login=true).